# How to pass an array element to another array to store in database in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am facing one problem in passing the array elements to another array...

```
$order=$this->ro_model->get_ro_details($order_id);
```

By using above function i will get query results into array name called $order.

Now i had form when it submits i will get some data from that form that i am saving in another name called $order_details.

```
$order_data=array(

    'amount'=>$this->input->post('amount'
);
```

Now i wanna save both the arrays data in one table in database. For that what i thought was i can pass first array data to second array data and i will save all the data in one array. Then later i will send that array to a function which will insert the data into database.

```
$this->ro_model->add_amount($order_data);
```

My problem how to pass that first array data to second array...........

- Note: All these are i am doing in codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge() function. Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 ways

1. array_push **Push one or more elements onto the end of array** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
2. array_merge **Merge one or more arrays** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php